# Using multiple data sources in a Quarkus application

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quarkus, quarkus-reactive

I am trying to develop a quarkus application that uses PostgreSQL database. Also I have a scheduler that is configured to work using jobrunr. Is it possible that I use two different PostgreSQL databases with one configured as a reactive connection and the other as jdbc connection?

Is having something like both possible,

quarkus.datasource.jobs.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database1

and

quarkus.datasource.reactive.url=vertx-reactive:postgresql://localhost:5432/database2

Comment: I dont think you can combine reactive driver and non-reactive driver at the same time in quarkus. You may need to create config in programmatically and not using Quarkus out of the box feature (convention over configuration)